# Options for creating custom dialogs in Sitecore

Tags: iframe, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I need to implement some pop-up dialogs in sitecore. The popups are used in an existing angular site and I would like to reuse as much as possible.

Use case: From a sitecore form activate the dialog, init the dialog with data from the sitecore field. If the user presses OK, then write back the new value to the site core field.

I know that sitecore has an IFrame type but I know that the browser will not allow me to write back to the parent window from a site in another domain.

So what options do I have?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you want to write content into sitecore? Is it user created content or is this some support for experience editor? If it is prior, then you should create a separate controller for the popups and use them as shared factories in angular i.e the popup would be a separate rendering (making it modular) with its own controller binding

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to communicate cross iframes and cross domains by posting it between, see example [here](https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe)

Comment: Thanks that is actually what I am trying right now. Dont know why you have been voted down. Its a qualified answer.

Comment: Glad to hear, let me know if you run into any issues with this approach. Have successfully done this in the past.